# What is this effect called?

Tags: sound, electronic-music, effects

There is a type of effect in music which I would like to replicate when making music in Apple Garageband. It sounds as though the EQ is being played with causing the music to sound as though it is traveling (if that makes sense). An example of this is found in Rhianna's song Desperado:

from 2:03-2:17. Does this effect have a name? Does anyone know how to produce it in garageband?

thanks

Comment: This question is off topic for this site, so I will just point out that you’re right the EQ is being played with.

Answer (score 1):

That's a filter sweep. More specifically, a resonant low pass filter sweep. It sounds like the drums are grouped in a track and the LPF is applied to the group.

Answer (score 1):

As Schizomorph said, that's a filter eq sweep. It is a common trick on equalizer simply add a filter and move it in time. That gives a virtual "movement" to your sound due to human psychoacoustic perception on different frequencies. I don't know anything about Garageband, but in all others major DAWs, to make this trick you just need to make an "envelope" of your eq in the track you want to apply the effect, "arm" your eq plugin (on "write mode") so it can store the positions to the "envelope", and then perform the move of the filter in real time while the song is playing. Just don't forget to turn again your plugin into "read" mode, so you can hear what you did when you replay it again.